# Django Admin Page, Part addition

Tags: python, html, django

OperationalError at /admin/parts/part/add/
no such table: parts_part

It keeps showing this error no matter how many times I have edited the models.py and admin.py code, whenever I try to add a part as a superuser it is showing the same error

Comment: Did you create and run migrations to actually create the table?

Comment: yes, i did that

Comment: Please update the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

After creating or altering model run below codes

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```